# What is the pop up that shows when you press a button called? [Xcode]

Tags: xcode

I'm looking through the Object Library in Xcode and I'm not seeing what this is (shown below). I'm guessing it's something specific because it has the arrow part indicating what button it's coming from.

[image: Pop up from button]

Answer (score 0):

It's a UIPopover, controlled by a UIPopoverController and you won't find it in the Object Library.  You build it as a normal UIView and then present it as a popover using the controller.

[UIPopoverController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/index.html)